# Current Sensing IC (MAX9929F) Query

Tags: current, resistors, sensor, current-measurement, measurement

I am using a MAX9929F Current sensing IC and I have a question to someone to may have used it before, or may have some experience with these types of circuits.

The circuit I built around the IC is the recommended circuit in the Datasheet. (Not much, just a current sense resistor, decoupling capacitors and a filter).

I am converting the output voltage of the sensor to current by proportionality, since it is a linear device. However the weird thing that I can't understand is that the constant of proportionality is not constant.

That is, for example, when you increase current up to 600mAh, and the output voltage is 2.15, then you decrease the current to 0mAh and increase it up again to 600mAh, and then the output voltage of the sensor is 2.2V.

This changes every time. (Hence I can't read the current accurately)
I would appreciate some hint to were the issue might lie, since I don't know where the error might be coming from since there is no other circuit that might be interacting with it.

Could it be that I am not using a purpose made current sense resistor ? (I don't think this is an issue since the input signal is DC)

Comment: Ah is not a unit of current, but of charge. Are you sure you're applying the right formulas here?

Comment: Yes, I think I might have found the error. I changed the sense resistor to a proper current sense resistor and it seems to be making the difference. I will not answer the questionsince I am not 100 percent sure, and I don't want to write false information.